# Help me fix problem about call function in the same class in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller with 2 functions :

```
function add($reply = NULL)
{

}
function submit()
{
    ...
    $this->add(validation_errors());
}
```

Add() function show view add_form.

In submit() function, i valid values of form and send result back add().

But...it redirect to error page (article/13.html - not found) ?

PS: I checked it and realized that it can show result in submit() function by print_r(validation_errors()).

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter generally form handling is done in the same controller function as the form submitting it.you do this by adding an if function to the code:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()) {
    // here is where the code for processing your form goes. Eg,
    $this->model->add("this");
    redirect("");
}
// Here you load the view, which should have validation_errors()
// where you want the errors to appear.
```

Comment: add() function in controller, not in model. By the way, i fixed it. thank u for reply ! ^ ^

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded more clearly, the add() function was an imaginary add() function in the model. Not the one in the controller. It's good practice to do form validation in CoderIgniter the way I demonstrated above as it is how the form validation library is made to work.